# Sable Ranch Dragon's Head set/prop?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, props, film-location

[Sable Ranch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie_ranch#Sable_Ranch), a California ranch used as an outdoor filming location for numerous films and TV shows, was hit by a wildfire on July 24th. [CNN ran a story about the wildfire](http://www.cnn.com/2016/07/26/us/california-wildfires/index.html) which included this photograph:

[image]

Does anyone recognize the dragon's head structure on the left side of the picture?

Comment: Damn, that looks familiar...now it's gonna drive me *crazy!*

Comment: Though I know it is not correct, It does resemble the Vol prop from the original Star Trek episode "The Apple."

Comment: @Vicpylon That was my thought too, initially but it's too big.

Comment: Something related to *"V - the Series"*...perhaps?

Comment: Of course, it could be something in course of production...

Comment: It is too large and I believe all the sets for trek were at  Desilu studios. They are long destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New show called *Ultimate Beastmaster*, a Netflix competition series produced by Sylvester Stallone that was [filmed on Sable Ranch](http://www.nbclosangeles.com/news/local/Historic-Movie-Ranch-Destroyed-Sand-Fire.html). Here's the poster:

[image]

Comment: Embellished it a bit, if that's OK.

Comment: Of course, no problem. Nice work Walt.

Comment: You seem to have multiple accounts now. If you'd like to merge them, you can use the "contact" button at the bottom of the page. Please don't use answers to post comments. If you were still in the same account as your answer, you'd be able to post comments (on your answer). I encourage you to actually create an account rather than continuing to post without registering. :D

Comment: Adding to @SlowBlade's answer, [someone on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/4uunyh/sable_ranch_dragons_head/d5sz11u) found some pictures of the structure [on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/david.timberlake/posts/10206420357896795): [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/46e2M.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/46e2M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is the set for an upcoming Netflix show called Ultimate Beastmaster. I found the set on Google Earth, and apparently, the dragon is in the location of ABC's game show **Wipeout.** The dragon is located on the former areas of the Qualifier and Round 2.